# Export R function to excel

Tags: r, excel, data-science

At work, we have a tool written in R, as well as a legacy version of the same thing written as an Excel Spreadsheet (we're working on getting rid of that, but for now it's still here).

I've written some new function in R, let's say

```
predictor <- function(value) return(predict(model, x=value))
```

(in reality, it's a bit more complex, but close enough for the sake of this question)

We'd like to back-port said function into the old Excel version of the tool, so I am looking for a way bring that R function (the function itself, not the output) into an Excel spreadsheet.

I don't really care if it's transpiled into an Excel-Formula, a VBA snippet, called directly, or whatever.
All I need is the ability to write a value into a cell in Excel, throw that function at it, and get the result back in another cell.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If your model is a linear model or a glm, it should be pretty trivial to turn the `predict` into an Excel formula. In other cases it will depend on the complexity and type of model. Otherwise googling "call R from Excel" turned up the [excel.link package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/excel.link/vignettes/CallingRFromExcel.html).

Comment: sadly, I don't think it's a linear model. In this specific case, it's a spline with special properties. Doable to "hand-roll" an Excel version, but not really something we would like to spend any more resources on than absolutely necessary.
That package looks nice. After some consideration, it's sadly not suited for our use case, since we can't assume everyone has R installed.